# Powershell script Trigger an release pipeline using Devops API

Tags: azure-devops, azure-powershell, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I am trying to create a Powershell script create a new release using DevOps API.

I can see the pipeline information using invoke rest method but not able to trigger a pipeline. Can I get some assistance here.?

Thanks,
Venkatraman

Answer (score 1):

It's not documented very well, but to start the release you have to update the status to `inProgress`.

```
$updateReleaseUri = "$($vrsmBaseUri)_apis/Release/releases/$($releaseId)/environments/$($environmentId)?api-version=6.0-preview"
$updateReleaseJsonBody = @{status = 'inProgress' }
$updateReleaseJsonBody = $updateReleaseJsonBody | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 100

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $updateReleaseUri -Method Patch -Headers $headers -Body $updateReleaseJsonBody -ContentType 'application/json'
```

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/update-release-environment?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

Answer (score 0):

You can use the specific endpoint "[**Releases - Create**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/releases/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)" to trigger the release pipeline.

The required parameter you need to provide at least to this endpoint is the **`definitionId`** of the release pipeline that you want to trigger.

Below is the complete PowerShell script of a demo as reference. I have tested with this script, and it can work well as expected.

```
$pat = '{Personal Access Token}'
$base64AuthInfo = [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f "", $pat)))

$headers = New-Object "System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[[String],[String]]"
$headers.Add("Authorization", ("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo))
$headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")

$uri = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/release/releases?api-version=6.0"

$body = '{ "definitionId": {definitionId} }'

Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri -Headers $headers -Body $body -Method POST | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 10
```